# Unable to import DataLoader in the python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have installed DataLoader using pip, but could not able to import it in the python script.

**Code**

```py
import dataloader
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import dataloader
  File "C:\Users\anand.nataraj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\dataloader\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dataloader import read_data_sets
ImportError: cannot import name 'read_data_sets' from 'dataloader' (C:\Users\anand.nataraj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\dataloader\__init__.py)
```

As mentioned below dataloader is installed successfully:
`python -m pip install dataloader`

```
Requirement already satisfied: dataloader in c:\users\anand.nataraj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (2.0)
```

But throwing the error shown above while importing in the script.

Answer (score 1):

The package/library is broken.

I have yet to find a decent description of what this library does documented anywhere. Checking https://pypi.org/project/dataloader/#description doesn't help and the fact that latest release was in 2016, I would suggest finding another library that suits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pycharm to run your code you need to adjust the python interpreter under Setting> Project interpreter. Check this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-interpreter.html) for the documentation.